# What's the most difference between Activiti 5.0 , 6.0 and 7.0?

Tags: activiti

Now I'm using Activiti5.18 , am I have necessary to learn the newest version of Activiti 6.0 or even Activiti 7.0 ? Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 2):

1. From 5 to 6, the main difference are engine internals, performance improvements and removed the PVM layer that was introduced in jBPM 4
2. Activiti 7 is focused on cloud deployments, but you can still pick up the base framework and embed it in your application. If you are looking into cloud native applications and microservices, this is your version. Beta1 should be released shortly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Activiti 7.0.0.GA is compiled for Java 11